# Замена репозитория на сервере

Tags: github

Помогите пожалуйста решить один вопрос:
Есть сервер, на сервере проект, проект крутится в приватном репозитории одного пользователя. Этот пользователь больше не работает с проектом и хочет удалить репозиторий. У меня есть новый пользователь с проплаченным аккаунтом и я хотел бы сделать так, чтобы владение этим репозиторием перешло мне. Могу ли я это как то устроить или обязательно надо создавать там новый репозиторий от нового пользователя? Или достаточно клонировать тот репозиторий, который есть сейчас и после того как старый пользователь удалит у себя проект, он продолжит жить, так как я его клонировал себе?

Comment: git изначально задумывался не привязанным к серверу, в каждом клоне репозитория находится полная его копия, и он должен продолжить жить. Но issues, pull requests и прочей сторонней дребедени это не касается, это уже фичи конкретного сервера

Comment: В настройках репозитория нашел интересную вещь, которая походу дела и даст мне необходимый результат - http://prntscr.com/i2ks6r